# can i adopt model property in the view asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my code

```
@{
            var splitResult = (ViewBag.Linguas.ToString()).Split(','); }
            @foreach (var x in splitResult)
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title_PT, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title_PT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title_PT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                @x
            }
```

ok, as you can see i am splitting the viewbag.linguas. the outcome is PT and EN for example, i want to use the foreach to create dynamicaly fields for all the language I allow in the database.

I want to change the name **model => model.title_pt to model=> model.title_x**

Any suggestions
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Html.Editor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions(v=vs.118).aspx) instead and pass your property name to it

```
@Html.Editor("model.title_" + x , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessage("model.title_" + x, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```